# Bootstrap 4 navbar brand does not change when maximize the screen

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with my navigation bar.

I'm using Bootstrap 4 Beta. My problem is when i change the navbar-expand-...

The navbar-brand goess something like this.

```
COMPANY
NAME
```

But i want it like this.

```
COMPANY NAME
```

EDIT:

Code navbar:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" role="navigation">
        <!-- Navigation Bar Brand -->
        <span class="h2" class="navbar-brand mb-0">COMPANY NAME</span>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please provide the code which you've tried so we can reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should solve the problem. Tested on all screen sizes -lg -md -sm

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Company Name</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
</nav>
```